# Update fails because Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I Get the following error when i try to update my table although there's n't any sub query :

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

---

MY QUERY :

```
UPDATE  t1 
SET t1.modified = 2
FROM TransActions AS t1
INNER JOIN Ruser R
ON t1.USERID = r.USERID
WHERE  r.dep_code = 54 and r.dep_year =2014
and YEAR(t1.checktime) =2016 and MONTH(t1.checktime) =1 and  t1.modified   = 0
```

---

The data selected like this :

```
USERID  empNum
3090    25
3090    25
2074    464
```

---

According to the comments my update trigger :

```
after update 
as

declare @userid int , @date date 


if (select userid from inserted)<>(select userid from deleted )
raiserror ('YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO PERFORME THIS ACTION',10 , 1)
ELSE
begin 
    set nocount on;

    set @userid = (select userid from inserted)
    set @date = (select convert(date , checktime) from inserted)


    exec calc_atten @date , @userid 
end
```

Comment: I don't think the above update query will give the error you mentioned.

Comment: Is there a trigger for update on TransActions table? if so, then perhaps that is the source if the error.

Comment: Then do you have trigger on `TransActions` table

Comment: @ZoharPeled : yeah there's a trigger on `TransActions `

Comment: Then post the trigger code

Comment: Then that is probably the source of the error. if you can't find it yourself, post the trigger code and we will try to help.

Comment: when more than one row is updated your trigger fail. Keep in mind that trigger will not execute for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers are executed per **statement**, not per **row**, that's the source of your error.
Your trigger assumes that the inserted and deleted tables will only ever have one row, however that is simply wrong.
The number of rows in the inserted / deleted tables is the number of rows effected by the DML statement (update/insert/delete).

I don't know what the procedure `calc_atten` does, but you need to find a way to execute it's logic on a set level and not on scalar variables as it does now.

Your condition at the beginning of the trigger should be changed to fit a multi-row update.
One way to do it is this: (I could probably write it shorter and better if I would have known the table's structure)

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM deleted d 
    INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON d.[unique row identifier] = i.[unique row identifier]
    WHERE i.userId <> d.UserId
)
```

*[unique row identifier] stands for any column or column combination that is unique per row in that table. If the unique row identifier contains the UserId column then this will not work properly.

Comment: . . The logic is right but the code is wrong.  Two userids could be switched, and your condition would not catch this.

Comment: ... @GordonLinoff Correct. I had a feeling something is wrong but didn't have the time to check myself. edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is ok.  The problem is the trigger.  `inserted` and `deleted` are tables (well, really views but that is irrelevant), so they can contain multiple rows.

Assuming that `transactions` has a primary key, you can check the update by doing

```
declare @userid int , @date date ;

if (exists (select 1
            from inserted i
            where not exists (select 1
                              from deleted d
                              where d.transactionid = i.transactionid and
                                    d.userid <> i.userid
                             )
           )
   )
begin
    raiserror ('Changing user ids is not permitted', 10 , 1);
end;
else begin 
    set nocount on;

    declare icursor cursor for select userid, checktime from inserted;
    open icursor;

    fetch next from icursor into @userid, @date;

    while not @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        exec calc_atten @date, @userid 
        fetch next from icursor into @userid, @date;
    end;

   close icursor; deallocate icursor;
end;
```

Cursors are not my favorite SQL construct.  But, if you need to loop through a table and call a stored procedure, then they are appropriate.  If you can rewrite the code to be set-based, then you can get rid of the cursor.

Comment: Cursors? really? besides the fact that they are performance killer, I find them a pain in the neck. btw, now It's my turn - you forgot to add another fetch next inside the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

Try using distinct like this:

```
UPDATE  t1 
SET t1.modified = 2
FROM TransActions AS t1
INNER JOIN (select distinct userid from Ruser
            where r.dep_code = 54 and r.dep_year = 2014 ) R
ON t1.USERID = r.USERID
WHERE YEAR(t1.checktime) =2016 and MONTH(t1.checktime) =1 and  t1.modified   = 0
```

BTW - I don't see any subquery here, so its weird thats the error you get, I have a feeling the error doesn't occurs because of that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct to return unique userid's:

```
UPDATE TransActions 
SET modified = 2
WHERE YEAR(checktime) = 2016
AND   MONTH(checktime = 1
AND   modified = 0
AND   userid IN ( SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM Ruser r WHERE  r.dep_code = 54 and r.dep_year =2014 );
```