# SQL Server 2012: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server-2012

Here is the dynamic query that its created:

```
Update form.CP_DEMOG
set
    [field_id] = '1984',
    ChangeReason= 'Initial',
    ModifiedBy = 'usr1',
    ModifiedDate=GETDATE(),
    status = (CASE WHEN status=0 or status is null or status=7 THEN 1 else status END)
where id = 17 and coalesce(status,0) <> 8
```

But I receive this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I cant find where it returns more that one value.

Comment: I also can't find where it returns more than one value.  Are you sure that you aren't running some cached version of an earlier update query which did actually have this problem?

Comment: Probably a trigger on the table. And also probably it assumes `INSERTED` or `DELETED` will contain exactly one row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update fails because Subquery returned more than 1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253299/update-fails-because-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value)

Comment: [And another fresh from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105783/mssql-case-when-statement-error/49105968#49105968)